# Is it possible to execute read only cypher queries from java?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to know just what the title says.

The reason I'd want this is to permit constrained read-only cypher queries to be executed; the data results would later be interpreted and serialized by a separate API layer.

I've seen code that makes basic assumptions in an attempt to mimic this behavior, e.g. the code might filter out any Cypher query that contains certain special words associated with write query structures (`merge`, `create`, `delete`, `set`, and so on).

This approach tends to be limited and naive though; if it very simply looks for those tokens, it would prevent a query like `MATCH n WHERE n.label =~ '.*create.*' RETURN n` even though it's a read-only query.

I'd really prefer not to do a full parse on a candidate query and then descend through the AST trying to figure out whether something is read-only or not (although I would gladly accept an answer that shows how to do this easily in java)

**EDIT** - I'm aware it's possible to start the entire database in read-only mode via the configuration property `read_only=true`, but this would be undesirable; no other aspect of the java API would be able to change the database.

**EDIT 2** - I found another possible strategy, but I'm not sure of its advisability.  Comments welcome on this, and potential downsides:

```
try (Transaction ignore = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    ExecutionResult result = executionEngine.execute(query);
    // Do nifty stuff with result, then...

    // Force transaction to fail.
    ignore.failure();
}
```

The idea here is that if queries happen within transactions and the transaction is always force-failed, then nothing can ever be written to the DB no matter what the result.

Comment: I'm unaware of such possibility, but curious to see if there are ways. Since Neo4j 2.2 is introducing basic auth, I would expect them to introduce soon multiple users and role-based access, features which have been demanded for a long time. It's not something that can be easily bolted on from outside and I've heard it should be fairly straightforward within their (internal) APIs.

Comment: I updated with a second edit - one possibility.  Not sure how wise it is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read-only Cypher is (not yet) directly supported. However I can think of two workarounds for that:

1) assuming you're running a Neo4j enterprise cluster: you can set `read_only=true` on one instance. That instance is then used for the read only queries where the other cluster instances are used for r/w. A load balancer in front of the cluster can be set up to send the requests to the right instance.

2) Use a `TransactionEventHandler` that vetos a transaction if its `TransactionData` contains write operations. Just for fun I've invested some minutes to implement that, see https://github.com/sarmbruster/read-only-cypher - feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check this code out.  What do you think about the "intentionally failing the transaction" approach?  (Edit 2 in the post)

Comment: "intentionally failing the transaction" will work for embedded usage. However you cannot hook into the Cypher endpoint in a server deployment with this approach.